# How can I check in my bashrc if an alias was already set

Tags: bash

How can I check in my `.bashrc` if an alias was already set.

When I source a `.bashrc` file, which has a function name, say *fun*, and my current environment has an alias as *fun* also.

I tried `unalias` fun, but that will give me an error that fun not found when my environment wont have that alias already.

So in my `.bashrc`, in my fun function I want to check if alias was set, then `unalias` that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you just want to make sure that the alias doesn't exist, just unalias it and redirect its error to /dev/null like this:

```
unalias foo 2>/dev/null
```

You can check if an alias is set with something like this:

```
alias foo >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "foo is set as an alias" || echo "foo is not an alias"
```

As stated in the manpage:

```
For each name in the argument list for which no  value  is  sup-
plied,  the  name  and  value  of  the  alias is printed.  Alias
returns true unless a name is given for which no alias has  been
defined.
```

Comment: @BrianHorakh I guess you meant this for the answer below :) mine doesn't use grep

Comment: Note that this solution is subject to errors from typos that can be hard to find. E.g., `unaalias foo 2>/dev/null || echo "The foo alias existed and has been undefined"` will always print that it existed even if it didn't exist and will not undefine it if it does exist; you will never see the `bash: unaalias: command not found` error message that tells you what's really going on. ¶ I suggest using [Bob Stack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67025232/107294), which does not have this issue; it ensures that you will see error messages related to programming errors.

Comment: here's a [patch for bash](https://github.com/bminor/bash/compare/master...mitchnull:bash:add-quiet-mode-to-unalias) to add `-q` to `unalias` :)

Answer (score 15):

Just use the command `alias` like

```
alias | grep my_previous_alias
```

Note that you *can* actually use `unalias`, so you could do something like

```
[ `alias | grep my_previous_alias | wc -l` != 0 ] && unalias my_previous_alias
```

That will remove the alias if it was set.

Comment: I used this to test for `la` between my mac and linux machines. In my .bash_profile on mac, I have `alias la='ls -GA` (because G is color) and then in my `.bashrc` I have `function checkLa(){ if [ "$(alias | grep la)" == "ls -GA" ]; then echo "mac user!"; return 0; fi echo "linux user!"; alias la='ls -A --color=auto' }; checkLa()`. I knew that alias returned all of the aliases too, but I just didn't think of it! :D

Comment: You have a possible bug, until you tighten up the grep i.e. : alias -p | grep "foo=" by using an = you reduce the risk of partially matching, in my case the alias is very short (two characters) and therefore triggers incorrectly because it matches others. –

Answer (score 8):

You can use `type` to see if the command exists, or whether is alias or not.

It'll return error status, if the command is not found.

For example, I'm defining the following alias:

```
$ alias foo="printf"
```

Then check the following scenarios:

```
$ type foo >/dev/null && echo Command found. || echo Command not found.
Command found.
```

or specifically for alias:

```
$ alias foo && echo Alias exists || echo Alias does not exist.
```

or to check whether it's alias or regular command:

```
$ grep alias <(type foo) && echo It is alias. || echo It is not.
```

To check if the alias is defined in your *rc* files, it needs to be checked manually e.g. by:

```
[ "$(grep '^alias foo=' ~/.bash* ~/.profile /etc/bash* /etc/profile)" ] && echo Exists. || echo Not there.
```

Answer (score 6):

Good bash-specific solution to check aliases is using `BASH_ALIASES` array, e.g.:

```
$ echo ${BASH_ALIASES[ls]}
```

Comment: `[[ ${BASH_ALIASES[foo]} ]] && unalias foo` would do the trick, right?

Comment: This seems like the cleanest way with no external commands involved.

Comment: @codeforester, `[[ ${BASH_ALIASES[foo]} ]] && unalias foo` is incorrect (alias may exist and be empty : `alias foo=`). I use instead `[[ -v BASH_ALIASES[foo] ]] && unalias foo`

Answer (score 6):

```
# Test if alias of name exists, and then remove it:
[ "$(type -t name)" = "alias" ] && unalias name

# Test if function of name exists, and then remove it:
[ "$(type -t name)" = "function" ] && unset -f name
```

Comment: This is a nice technical solution

Comment: But I get `bad option: -t`

Comment: You might not be using bash?

Comment: I am using gitbash on Windows

Comment: Check your documentation. "Git for Windows provides a BASH emulation ..." .  The emulation may not be a complete implementation.

Comment: @BobStack Git for Windows is  not emulating Bash, it provides actual Bash. (This is what comes up by default in mintty, the terminal emulator it also provides.) On my (somewhat old) installation of GfW, `echo $BASH_VERSION` produces `4.4.23(1)-release`. (And yes, `type -t` works fine for me.)

Comment: @FrankFang Sounds like you might be using the wrong shell or something like that. `type -t` works fine for me when I Git Bash from the Start or context (right-click) menus. You can try: 1) `echo $BASH_VERSION` to confirm you're really in a Bash shell; 2) `type type` to confirm it says `type is a shell builtin`; 3) `type --help` to see the parameters it accepts. And, of course, look carefully to see you're typing the right command; it's easy to type, e.g., `test` instead of `type`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to make your bashrc file simpler:

1. Make sure that an alias exists.
2. Unalias it.
3. Define the function

---

```
alias fun=''
unalias fun
fun ()
{
   # Define the body of fun()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288512/how-can-i-test-if-a-particular-alias-is-defined):

```
if alias <your_alias_name> 2>/dev/null; then 
  do_something
else 
  do_another_thing; 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this function based on [noonex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41868737/6862601) answer:

```
unalias_if() {
    local alias_name
    for alias_name; do
        [[ ${BASH_ALIASES[$alias_name]} ]] && unalias "$alias_name"
    done
}
```

and it can be invoked safely as

```
unalias_if alias1 alias2 ...
```

Comment: `[[ -v BASH_ALIASES[$alias_name] ]]` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to @noonex's proposal, but can handle empty aliases with :

```
[[ -v BASH_ALIASES[foo] ]] && unalias foo
```

This will work even if `foo` alias exists but is empty :

```
alias foo=
[[ ${BASH_ALIASES[foo]} ]] && echo unalias1
[[ -v BASH_ALIASES[foo] ]] && echo unalias2
```

Output :

```
unalias2
```

Would you need a function like `@codeforester`'s solution, you should change `${BASH_ALIASES[$alias_name]}` accordingly.